# How can I quickly create a class in the right place when following TDD using Visual Studio/ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, tdd, resharper

Suppose I'm following TDD and using VS/ReSharper. I start out writing a test like this:

```
[TestFixture]
class FooFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldDoSomething()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
    } 
}
```

At this point, `Foo` doesn't exist. ReSharper suggests the option of creating the class, but it puts it right next to my test class in my test project, not in my real project. So I have it create the class, then move it to a new file, then move the file to the right place, and finally fix the namespace. This seems like a lot of work.

Is there a more efficient way to quickly create the `Foo` class and put it in the right place? It seems like the 'right place' could be guessed from the namespace of my test project.

Comment: Alt+Enter for quick fixes, C+S+R for Move To Folder..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Move types into matching class](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_Types_into_Matching_Files) refactoring is used for this purpose.

You're expected to generate a number of business logic types in the current test class and then move them to matching files/namespaces in one go.

Note that this refactoring is available in the text editor and on Solution Explorer nodes, meaning that you can batch-apply it to a heck lot of files.

Comment: That does solve part of the problem, in that it creates separate files. It does not move the classes to the correct project.

Comment: Right. There's also Move to Folder. [This video](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/refactor-on-the-project-level) shows how this combo is used